# Retrieving a model and updating its (polymorphic) related models in Laravel 7

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-7

I have 2 models

**Asset**

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Attribute::class, 'attributable');
}
```

**Attribute**

```
public function attributable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

I would like to retrieve an **Asset** and update its **Attributes** like...

```
public function update(Request $request, Asset $asset){

    $array = [{id: 1, name:'foo', value: ''}, {id: 2, name: 'bar', value: ''}];
    //update should happen here
    $asset->attributes()->saveMany($array);
}
```

I can retrieve the relationship, no worries but I know that this wouldn't work because saveMany() requires an instance of a model as its arguments. So I tried this...

```
foreach ($array as $a){
    $update = Attribute::find($a->id); ///<---this causes an error
    $update = Attribute::find($a['id']); ///<---this way as well  
}
```

I know I must be missing something really basic here but... is there an eloquent way to do this? I've been scrubbing the online documents to no avail. Any help or guidance at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Problem solved: I used a **foreach** loop to iterate like:
`foreach($asset->attributes as $attribute){ 
     $array->firstWhere('id', $attribute->id;
     $attribute->update(['value' => $a['value']));
}`

Answer (score 0):

First this is not valid `php`,

```php
$array = [{id: 1, name:'foo', value: ''}, {id: 2, name: 'bar', value: ''}];
```

Should be like this:

```php
$array = [['id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo', 'value'=> ''], ['id'=> 2,'name'=> 'bar', 'value'=> '']];
```

Second you are basically asking for `bulk update` which is still not in `laravel` yet.

See this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/575), and there is a potential solution there.

But what you can do is this:

```php
foreach ($array as $a) {    
    $asset->attributes()->where('id', $a['id'])->update(unset($a['id']));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Andy Song. It so happens that this is what I get from the js frontend. I did some more digging and found some methods that are pretty handy [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections).

Comment: @ChrisMayers your question is wanting to update db, the link you found is laravel collection which has nothing to do with db.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself properly. What I did was, loop through the `attributes` (foreach loop) and used the  `firstWhere` (found in the link I sent) method on the `array` to find the element with the matching `id` and use that to update each attribute.